# C# calling python interpreter

Tags: c#, python, interpreter

I am new to C# and I tried to execute a python program using the `ProcessStartInfo` class. I followed [this link](https://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput)  and did the same. However, I cannot get any redirect output. I tried to execute the Python interpreter with the argument and there were no problems. However, I saw the console pop up and then went away immediately. There was no output print. I tried to use the method `process.waitForExit(`) but the console also went away. Any ideas?

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe";
            start.Arguments = @"C:\Users\test\test.py";
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            start.RedirectStandardError = true;
            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {

                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.Write(result);
                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is it possible that it's printing out an error? Try reading from StandardError instead of StandardOutput to see if that shows anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your application from VS then VS closes application console after finishing execution. Try to add `Console.ReadLine()` as the last line in your program.

```
using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(result);
    }
 }
 Console.ReadLine();
```